# Put centered text in bottom of image using overpic?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, overpic

I have a graph for which I want a centered x-label at the bottom. The idea is to use overpic and then insert som text at the bottom using \put(50,1){some x-label}.

The problem is that \put places the START of the text relative to the image. Is there a way to put the CENTER of the text relative to the image?

Code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{overpic}[width=0.8\textwidth]{graph}
        \put(50,1){some x-label}
    \end{overpic}
\end{center}
```

I also want a y-label rotated 90deg counter clockwise horisontally centered on the left side of the graph. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   \put(50,1){\makebox(0,0){some x-label}}
```

will put the (horizontal and vertical) centre of of the text at the specified position.

To rotate text you can use `\rotatebox`

```
   \put(50,1){\makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{90}{some x-label}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

With swiss army knife `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep = 0pt] (a) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[anchor=south,inner sep=1pt] at (a.south) {This is $x-$label};
    \node[anchor=south,inner sep=1pt,rotate=-90] at (a.west) {This is $y-$label};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `stackengine` package.  Here, the x-axis label is centered horizontally, with the offset to the bottom of the label specified from the bottom of the graph.  Likewise, the y-axis label is centered vertically, with the offset to the left of the label specified from the left of the graph.

EDITED to show that image aspect poses no problems; nor does math in label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-90}{This is my $y$-axis label}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{2pt}{This is my $x$-axis label}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-A}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your graph has no blank region in which to apply the labels, `\stackinset` can apply the labels outside of the image, by using negative offsets.  However, in this case, make the y-axis label the innermost nested inset, because an inset that extends above or below the base content (as does the x-label) effectively changes the image height for subsequent insets.  In contrast, extending out the left or right of the image does not change the effective width of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{b}{-12pt}{This is my x-axis label}{%
  \stackinset{l}{-12pt}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-90}{This is my y-axis label}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{example-image-A}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]